# How to get all multiple keys pressed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, game-development

i found this jsfiddle, that should show all keys pressed on the keyboard. The code looks fine, but it does not seem to work, at least on my keyboard: https://jsfiddle.net/HwR9N/3/

When i press all the arrow keys, only two of the keys get listed.

I work with a similar code, to create a javascript game, but i got the same problem there:

```js
//List of all keys pressed or up
    var keymap = [];
    window.addEventListener("keydown",
        function(e){
            keymap[e.keyCode] = true;
            checkCombinations(e);
        },
    false);
    
    window.addEventListener('keyup',
        function(e){
            keymap[e.keyCode] = false;
        },
    false);
```

A strange thing is, that the WASD keys work all at the same time.
Does anybody know a different method, that works on every keyboard? I haven't tried another keyboard yet. Im working on a HP Laptop. OS is Windows 10. Problem occurs in Chrome and Firefox.

Im thankfull for any advice.

Greets,
Florian

Comment: This is probably a hardware limitation and can't be solved in software. Some keyboards only let you press multiple buttons at once on the left-hand side to allow for gaming, while keeping the right hand side one or two keys only. It really depends on the keyboard.

Comment: I have 2 keyboards to test it with, one keyboard doesn't accept `A`,`W`,`G` (definitely not for gaming), while another accepts it, but doesn't accept `A`,`W`,`Q`. This proves that as @jabaa said, it hardware limitation.

Comment: Thank you very much jabaa and vanowm. This really helps me!